# Trying to check to see if a line contains something in the start and has a certain word in it

Tags: ruby, regex

returns 1 if the file contains the string "attach" on a line that doesn't
start with >. Return 0 otherwise. A script's return value is set as the parameter to
Ruby's exit function. After running the script, echo $? to check the returned value.

I'm working on this problem and have a basic understanding of what must be done. I need to first check if the line starts with >, then search for the exact word "attach", but I don't know how to actually code this in ruby and need some help. I feel dumb because I'm sure this is a simple thing to do and I'm stumped.

Thank you so much for any help.

Edit: you wanted to see what i had so far for code and it's not much but...
I know if i use something like  `^>` I can see if it starts with the > and I can just spell out "attach" to get that meaning I could use something ALMOST like `^> attach` except i need the negation of ^>, which I'm not sure how to do. I tried messing around with different spots of putting a ! to negate it, but didn't get any luck with that.

I also know that I can't just have it like that but I need something like (?'attach'), but am not fully sure what is the best way to do that.

Comment: You should share something you tried. We're not going to write code for you.

Comment: It really looks like you're asking us to do your homework for you. Show us what you've tried, and describe why it doesn't work. Give us some sample input and the expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the ruby String class: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/String.html. Note the start_with?() method and the match() method. You don't need a complex regex, you can use a compound if statement:

```
line = "abc attach"

if (not line.start_with?('>')) and line.match("attach")
  puts 'yes'
else 
  puts 'no'
end

--output:--
yes
```

> to get that meaning I could use something ALMOST like ^> attach except
>   i need the negation of ^>, which I'm not sure how to do.

You can use a character class: [>], which matches '>', and then negate the class: [^>], which matches anything but a '>' character.

> also know that I can't just have it like that but I need something
>   like (?'attach'),

If you have to use a regex, then think of wording the regex like this:

```
1) You want to match the start of the string
2) Followed by any character that is not a '>' 
3) Followed by zero or more of any character  (see the regex character . and the modifier *)
4) Followed by the word 'attach'
```

Answer (score 0):

Rubular: a Ruby regular expression editor and tester

http://rubular.com/

This should get you started with regular expressions.

Comment: Try using the direct URL to Rubular, instead of a tracking URL via Google.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to match any non-">" character in a regex, you can use the negation symbol "^" within a custom character class (all characters within a set of square brackets [])

```
1.9.3-p448 :038 > one = "> line with"
 => "> line with"
1.9.3-p448 :039 > two = ">attach"
 => ">attach"
1.9.3-p448 :040 > three = "$#@asdfj>dsfkjhattach"
 => "$>dsfkjhattach"
1.9.3-p448 :041 > /^[^>].*attach/.match(one)
 => nil
1.9.3-p448 :042 > /^[^>].*attach/.match(two)
 => nil
1.9.3-p448 :043 > /^[^>].*attach/.match(three)
 => #<MatchData "$>dsfkjhattach">
```

So, a method that does what you are asking for would be:

```
def matchAttachNoAngleBracket(subject)
  /^[^>].*attach/.match(subject) ? "yes" : "no"
end
1.9.3-p448 :047 > matchAttachNoAngleBracket(one)
 => "no"
1.9.3-p448 :048 > matchAttachNoAngleBracket(two)
 => "no"
1.9.3-p448 :049 > matchAttachNoAngleBracket(three)
 => "yes"
```